# Does SQL Server 2019 Express support read-only mode?

Tags: entity-framework-core, sql-server-express

I'm using the Express edition for a small project, along with EF Core. Just wondering if I can separate a `DbContext` for queries only.

Comment: You're thinking of having 2 `DbContext` classes, one for queries, one for updates? But sharing a data model?

Comment: It's just a matter of correct user permissions, and Express supports those, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855692/set-sql-server-connection-to-readonly

Comment: @AnnL. Exactly.